# how to filter sar -d disk output tidily

Tags: bash, hard-drive, ubuntu-12.04, awk, sar

sar -D output-I would like a suitable command to run alongside stress -hdd but this is the output which sar -D 1 10 gives. I have filtered it using both `awk |'NR > 1 {printf "%4s%8s%8s\n",$13,$14,$15}'` and `awk 'NR > 1 {OFS="\t"; print $13,$14,$15}'` but the output is messy like the first instance below. How can I get it filtered to be more like the second output which i got at the ibm site?

```
   4296roryhbmc
    1944    rootal,
    3361    root
Tasks:     326total,
Cpu(s):25.7%us,54.1%sy,
Mem:2041916k
Swap:1046524kt    0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 268   957 
 34  17  49   0   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 279   679 
 49  31  21   0   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 334  1874 
  4   6  90   0   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 109   131 
 28  16  55   1   0   0|   0  4096B|   0     0 |   0     0 | 304   575 
 42  33  26   0   0   0|  20k  428k|   0     0 |   0     0 | 392  1343 
  4  10  86   0   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |  81   124 
  8  12  57  22   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 113   193 
  2   9  66  22   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |  74   126 
  4  12  84   0   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 |  92   140 
  8  21  54  17   0   0|   0     0 |   0     0 |   0     0 | 129   286 
  7  11  48  33   0  
*******************************
* Choose from the following: *
*******************************
* [1] Stress the CPU. *
* [2] Stress the Memory(RAM). *
* [3] Stress the disk drive. *
* [4] Stress the  hard disk drive. *
Press A to quit.
************************
Enter your menu choice [1-4]:
```

How can I edit it so it will only show this?

```
$ sar -d

SunOS unknown 5.10 Generic_118822-23 sun4u    01/22/2006

00:00:01   device       %busy   avque   r+w/s  blks/s  avwait  avserv
. cut ...
14:00:02   dad0             31     0.6      78   16102     1.9     5.3
           dad0,c            0     0.0       0       0     0.0     0.0
           dad0,h           31     0.6      78   16102     1.9     5.3
           dad1              0     0.0       0       1     1.6     1.3
           dad1,a            0     0.0       0       1     1.6     1.3
           dad1,b            0     0.0       0       0     0.0     0.0
           dad1,c            0     0.0       0       0     0.0     0.0
```

source: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-perfmonsar.html

I asked on stackoverflow and was advised to ask here instead. I want to run this command simultaneous to a stress command. If this command is not correct, does anyone know a disk stats command that can be used? I am looking for one that can be timed the same way vmstat/iostat can.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854311/how-to-filter-sar-d-disk-output-tidily?noredirect=1#comment45976890_28854311

Comment: does no one know how to do this?

Comment: Did you try `tr -d '\015'` as suggested on SO?